# Configure trackpoint on Dell Latitude 5470

Tags: 16.04, dell, trackpoint

I faced the problem of a very sensitive trackpoint on Ubuntu 16.04.
Here is my default settings:

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick':
    Device Enabled (140):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (266): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (268):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (269):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (261):    2, 8
    Device Node (262):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (305): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (307):  0
    Axis Labels (308):  "Rel X" (150), "Rel Y" (151)
    Button Labels (309):    "Button Left" (143), "Button Middle" (144), "Button Right" (145), "Button Wheel Up" (146), "Button Wheel Down" (147), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (148), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (149)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (310): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (311):    1
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (312):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (313): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (314): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (315):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (316):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (317):    1
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (318):   6, 7, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (319):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (320):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (321): 2
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (322):  0
```

I've tried to adjust Accel settings but only the only result I get is change of sensitivity on high speed moving. I can't lower the sensitivity of low speed moving so I can make the moves more precise. 
 I've heard that I can install a glidepoint driver, maybe this thing will help me.But I'm not sure how. So any help here?

**UPD**
 I found better explanation what is wrong with my trackpoint

I am unable to achieve acceptable results with all the different knobs that are available. If I tune down acceleration, I am able to do detailed pointing, but the stick is generally so slow, that it takes ages to cross the screen. On the other hand, if I increase the acceleration, even the slightest movement of the stick makes it jump significantly on the screen so that I am unable to do detailed selections.

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99860
here is the thread.

Answer (score 1):

To make your trackpoint more precise, just increase the `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` value (15 is fine for me):

```
xinput set-float-prop 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 15
```

#### Make it persistent

```
echo "xinput set-float-prop 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 15" >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

#### Not working ?

Find out your trackpoint device name , it's usually **DualPoint Stick** or something like that.

```
$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

List available properties, to see, if `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` is present

```
$ xinput list-props 13

Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   15.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (260):    2, 8
    Device Node (261):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (304): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (306):  0
    Axis Labels (307):  "Rel X" (149), "Rel Y" (150)
    Button Labels (308):    "Button Left" (142), "Button Middle" (143), "Button Right" (144), "Button Wheel Up" (145), "Button Wheel Down" (146), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (147), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (148)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (309): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (310):    1
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (311):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (312): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (313): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (314):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (315):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (316):    1
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (317):   6, 7, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (318):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (319):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (320): 2
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (321):  0
```

Finally, try not using literal names, but ids:

```
xinput set-float-prop 13 266 14
```

Comment: do you have 5470 laptop

Comment: nope,  Dell Latitude E7470 here ^^ .. do you have problems adjusting trackpoint sensitivity?

Comment: yes. I've updated my question. Please read it at the bottom of the q